# Force \includegraphics use specific file extension for all document

Tags: graphics

What is the way to force \includegraphics to use specific file extension for all document?

If I have in the folder `figure.pdf` and `figure.png`

`\includegraphics{figure}` command will use `figure.png`, if I need `*.pdf` I could force to use it by typing: `\includegraphics{figure.pdf}`

But if I need sometimes to compile document with all figures with `png` extension or `pdf`, what should I change in `graphics` package settings?